# Consultar um único item no banco de dados PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

A minha consulta só retorna um valor, e esse valor preciso usar em outra consulta. Como posso pegar esse valor sem colocar em um array?
Como está feito no código ele coloca o valor em um array, assim não consigo colocar na consulta.

```
       <?php

        $login_email;
        $login_senha;
        $sql = "SELECT idCliente FROM CLIENTES WHERE dsEmail='$login_email' and dsSenha='$login_senha'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        while ($idCliente = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
            echo $idCliente[0];
        }


        $sql = "SELECT dsProduto, vlUnitario from produtos, carrinhos_produtos,carrinhos where (produtos.idProduto = carrinhos_produtos.idProduto)
        and (carrinhos_produtos.idCarrinho = carrinhos.idCarrinho) and ($idCliente = carrinhos.idCliente)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só você ler apenas uma linha com fetch_assoc e utilizar posteriormente no que deseja

```
   <?php
        $login_email;
        $login_senha;
        $sql = "SELECT idCliente FROM CLIENTES WHERE dsEmail='$login_email' and dsSenha='$login_senha'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $idCliente = $row['idCliente'];

        $sql2 = "SELECT dsProduto, vlUnitario from produtos, carrinhos_produtos,carrinhos where (produtos.idProduto = carrinhos_produtos.idProduto)
                and (carrinhos_produtos.idCarrinho = carrinhos.idCarrinho) and ($idCliente = carrinhos.idCliente)";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        ...
    ?>
```